# How to permanently redirect an app engine service?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app running on gae, (angular and go) and I want to redirect any requests to a completely new service with a new domain. How would I do this?

I can see how to redirect http > https, but what if I wanted to redirect example-app-engine.appspot.com > new-service.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

1. From your domain registrar's end via forwarding/url redirect
2. Via [Meta Refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh). This is not suitable if you have lots of paths/pages on the original url and you want exactly the same path on the destination url
3. From your backend code