# How to route www to non-www URL using Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a custom domain "domain.tld". I followed the instructions via the "custom domains" tab in Google App Engine to configure everything. I had to add a secure handler to my app.yaml file to direct all http to https but I would also like to direct all [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld) to domain.tld and I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: See this response (it also applies to domains) - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824047/how-to-permanently-redirect-an-app-engine-service/69824958#69824958. We're using the first option for our website - https://nocommandline.com

Comment: @Mickey is my answer helpful?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to configure Google App Engine app.yaml file to force https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70458516/how-to-configure-google-app-engine-app-yaml-file-to-force-https)

Comment: No, that is also my post and the one recommendation on that page didn't yield any results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dispatch.yml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/reference/dispatch-yaml?authuser=0) as per app engine wildcard [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains?authuser=0#wildcards)

```
dispatch:
  # Default service serves the typical web resources and all static resources.
  - url: "www.domain.tld/*"
    service: default
```

Comment: is `default` supposed to be defined somewhere?

Comment: I tried this. It doesn't do anything...