# How to configure Google App Engine app.yaml file to force https

Tags: google-app-engine, yaml

How do I force all domain.tld and [www.domain.tld](http://www.domain.tld) to https://domain.tld? I was able to get close. If I uncomment by commented lines it will force everything but then everything in my static folder can't be accessed.

```
runtime: php74
env: standard
entrypoint: serve public/index.php

handlers:

#- url: /.*
#  script: auto
#  secure: always
#  redirect_http_response_code: 301

- url: /static
  static_dir: static
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this:

```
runtime: php74
env: standard
entrypoint: serve public/index.php

handlers:

- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /.*
  script: auto
  secure: always
  redirect_http_response_code: 301
```

The order is important because the first matching rule is used.

Comment: I did not know that! Thank you so very much for taking the time to respond.